# Change event in Android/custom event

Tags: android, events

i've a service polling for data every x minutes, the screen may be on/off on android, but, my services has to do its job of notifying the main activity that the data has changed(Main screen will update the data if the data is changed), is there a way to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use ContentObserver to achieve it. Register your Activity as ContentObserver, it will get notified whenever there's change in Data (Content).

Comment: I'm not workign on the DB, looks like the contentobserver is related to it. You think there is a way to implement app level notifications?